# Is Instagram provide an API which will take username and password and send follow requests to random users for android in kotlin or java or futter

Tags: android, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to create a simple android application in which user will enter username and password of the Instagram and the app will automatically send the follow request to user.

I have read some blog but can't find anything , what I need

Comment: That people would actually enter their IG credentials into _your_ app, is an absolute no-go to begin with. If you want to do anything via the official APIs - then you need to use the official authorization methods to begin with. But, there is no API to send follow requests.